# Saving multiple responses from foreach c#

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

Creating C#/.net application that gets services names from AWS using the cluster name. With the AWS .net SDK

Able to retrieve cluster names and save them in a list of strings:

```
AmazonECSClient client = new AmazonECSClient();
ListClustersRequest listClusterREquest = new ListClustersRequest();
var responseClusterList = await client.ListClustersAsync(listClusterREquest);
List<string> clusterArns = responseClusterList.ClusterArns;
```

Now trying to retrieve the list of services using the cluster names. I am having issues saving each response back to a list named serviceArns. It only saves the last response to the list called serviceArns. There should be about 20 responses saved to the list.

```
ListServicesRequest listRequest = new ListServicesRequest();
List<string> serviceArns = null;
ListServicesResponse responsethree = new ListServicesResponse();

foreach (var item in clusterArns)
      {
                listRequest.Cluster = item;
                ListServicesResponse listResponse = await client.ListServicesAsync(listRequest);
    serviceArns = listResponse.ServiceArns;


};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should intialise the list at the start and add elements as needed be. Currently with each iteration, the list gets set, where it should be adding it instead.

```
ListServicesRequest listRequest = new ListServicesRequest();
List<string> serviceArns = new();
ListServicesResponse responsethree = new ListServicesResponse();

foreach (var item in clusterArns)
{
    listRequest.Cluster = item;
    ListServicesResponse listResponse = await client.ListServicesAsync(listRequest);
    serviceArns.AddRange(listResponse.ServiceArns);
};
```

Comment: The line break after the `await`, triggers me, what kind of monster does that. *rage* :)

Comment: Thank you it is working with AddRange(). Since the response is a List<string> that is the reason we use AddRange() and not Add()?